# How to get value of custom dropdown product attribute?

Tags: magento-1.7, module, product-attribute, model, dropdown-attribute

I created a custom attribute in my products page. The attribute is a dropdown list.

The name of the attribute is `soldby`.

I want to extract the value of that attribute.

I wrote:

`$seller= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())
         ->getData('soldby');`

This returns me null.

If I do something similar to an attribute which is a textfield, it works fine.

How can I extract the option selected ?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());  

$product->getAttributeText('soldby');
```

Comment: From where do I get `$product` ?

Comment: $product is the product model - see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
$seller= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
$seller->getAttributeText('soldby');
```